# Why is this C# overload with nullables not ambiguous?

Tags: c#, compilation, overloading

Why does C# allow the following method overload:

```
void F(int a) { Console.WriteLine(1); }
void F(int? a) { Console.WriteLine(2); }
```

If I run that code:

```
A a = new A();
a.F(1);
```

it prints `1`. How does the compiler know which one to invoke. Isn't it ambiguous?

I thought the idea behind nullable types is that you might pass the value of the right type in or you might pass in `null`. So I should be able to call the first `F` with `(1)` and second `F` with `(1)` or `(null)`.

I have a runnable example [here](https://repl.it/repls/SizzlingInfiniteGigahertz).

**Update:**
After reading the answer, my confusion stemmed from that fact that I thought that nullable params were synonymous with optional params.

Indeed, replacing the second method with `void F(int a = 0);` leads to a compilation error.

Comment: It's definitely not ambiguous.  `Nullable<int>` and `int` are two different types.

Comment: No it's not ambigous, int != int?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Try again? Not sure what went wrong before.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Added an explanation. I guess when you put it that way it makes sense. They are certainly different types. But you don't have to pass in a value of type `Nullable`, right? I can pass in `1` and it will turn it into a `Nullable<int>`?

Comment: Oh I guess from the compiler's point of view, they're different types so of course it will compile. And from a run-time perspective, I'm forced to define a variable of type `int?` and pass it in to trigger the second case? I guess otherwise it doesn't know which `F` I want to call.

Comment: `1` literal is of type `int`. Since there is overload which takes exactly this type - it's preferred over another overload, to which type your argument (of type `int`) is implicitly convertible. That's quite common, the same happens if for example you have overloads with `int` and `object`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int?` is actually a `Nullable<int>` struct, so that differentiates the two.

The following call should print `2`

```
int? a = 0;
F(a);
```

Regarding the following call...

```
A a = new A();
a.F(1);
```

The `1` literal is an `int`, not an `int?`, so it goes to the `void F(int a)` method. If you were to pass `null` to the method, it cannot be an `int`, so it goes to the `void F(int? a)` method, since it is a datatype that could be null.

Both methods are capable of accepting the `1` value, but the compiler will choose the most specific overload, which in this case, is the one accepting exactly the same type, `int`.